# How to print an error message if input is not a number?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder how to print an error message if user's input is not a number.

```
Console.WriteLine("Water amount in ml:");
        int waterAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Most answers from other posts don't work, because `waterAmount` is a Int32, not a string.
Also, sorry if my English is weak, it's not my native language

Comment: Use `TryParse()` and if it is false write the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using C#'s `TryParse()` functions.
These attempt to convert values, but if they fail they return false rather than erroring.

I would suggest trying this code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Water amount in ml:");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

if (Int32.TryParse(input, out var value))
    // Do something here. The converted int is stored in "value".
else
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number");
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you did not accept the other answers. Maybe you want to make the user try again after he did not input a number. You can do that with a while loop, or easier, using the goto keyword. You simply put a tag before everything is happening (in my case, waterAmountInput), and if the input was not a number, you write your error message and go to the beginning again. Here is the code:

```
        int waterAmount;

        waterAmountInput:
        Console.Write("Water amount in ml: ");
        try
        {
            waterAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The water amount needs to be a number!");
            goto waterAmountInput;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's my first project ever and i really needed this advice.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TryParse` function:

```
Console.WriteLine("Water amount in ml:");
int waterAmount = 0;
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), waterAmount)) {

} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Error Message");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `TryParse` before presuming it to be a number.
After `Console.WriteLine` you can capture and parse the input and if `TryParse` returns `false`, you can display an error message.

Note: if the conversion succeeds the numeric value is available in the `waterAmt` local variable.

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Water amount in ml:");
var input = Console.ReadLine();
if(!int.TryParse(input, out int waterAmt))
      Console.WriteLine("Input is not a number");
```